# MySQL query DISTINCT, COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'm trying to use a SELECT DISTINCT to find out how many people have cars, how many have boats, now many bikes and so on, from this table

```
|   name   |   obj  |
---------------------
|  john    |  car   |
|  mary    |  boat  |
|  dave    |  car   |
|  james   |  bike  |
|  steve   |  car   |
|  walt    |  bike  |
```

ex: bike - 2

Comment: `select distinct` works on a row-basis. it's not filtering for distinct field contents. you need a `select obj, count(obj) ... group by obj` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query

```
SELECT obj, COUNT(name) as nb FROM table GROUP BY obj ORDER BY obj
```

Result ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e66180/2)):

```
|   obj    |   nb   |
---------------------
|  bike    |    2   |
|  boat    |    1   |
|  car     |    3   |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(obj = 'car') as car_count,
       sum(obj = 'boat') as boat_count
from your_table
```

Comment: Could work, but what if i have 100 types of objects? In my case I have 23 different objects. Thanks for the answer!